# Get data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a query regarding join . Basically there are two tables **product** and **product_boost** . The table **product_boost** has the `product_id` as foreign key which is also in **product** table .

I want to get the data using join which is available in both the tables, and if not only data from first table will come.

I am using right outer join, here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `vefinder_product` 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `vefinder_product_boost` ON `vefinder_product_boost`.`product_id`=`vefinder_product`.`product_id` 
WHERE `vefinder_product`.`status` = 1 
  AND `vefinder_product`.`post_type` != 5 
  AND `vefinder_product`.`country` IN('348') 
  AND `vefinder_product`.`product_stock` >0 
  AND `vefinder_product`.`product_in_stock` = 1 
  AND `vefinder_product_boost`.`target_age_from` >= 20 
  AND `vefinder_product_boost`.`target_age_to` <= 40  
ORDER BY `vefinder_product`.`is_boosted` DESC, 
         `vefinder_product`.`is_sponsered` DESC, 
         `vefinder_product`.`created_date` DESC LIMIT 21
```

How  can i achive the desired thing , because this is not working. I am using codeigniter php.

Comment: Did you try `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @Lithilion yes , sadly it is also not working

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: if you want to fetch match data only, you should use inner join

Comment: @SachinSarola i am not using inner join

Comment: _"...get the data using join which is available in both the tables, and if not only data from first table will come."_ is the definiton of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj post some sample data and out put in your question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `Left join` instead, if you want to get all the data from first (leftmost) table.
- Any `Where` conditions on tables other than the first table (leftmost), should be shifted to `ON` condition in `Left Join`. Otherwise, `Where` would filter out unmatched rows also (`null` in the right side tables).

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `vefinder_product` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `vefinder_product_boost` 
  ON `vefinder_product_boost`.`product_id`=`vefinder_product`.`product_id` AND 
     `vefinder_product_boost`.`target_age_from` >= 20 AND 
     `vefinder_product_boost`.`target_age_to` <= 40 
WHERE `vefinder_product`.`status` = 1 AND 
      `vefinder_product`.`post_type` != 5 AND 
      `vefinder_product`.`country` IN('348') AND 
      `vefinder_product`.`product_stock` >0 AND 
      `vefinder_product`.`product_in_stock` = 1 
ORDER BY `vefinder_product`.`is_boosted` DESC, 
         `vefinder_product`.`is_sponsered` DESC, 
         `vefinder_product`.`created_date` DESC 
LIMIT 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join and put where condition in ON cluase

```
SELECT * FROM `vefinder_product` 
left OUTER JOIN `vefinder_product_boost` ON `vefinder_product_boost`.`product_id`=`vefinder_product`.`product_id` 
  and `vefinder_product`.`status` = 1 
  AND `vefinder_product`.`post_type` != 5 
  AND `vefinder_product`.`country` IN('348') 
  AND `vefinder_product`.`product_stock` >0 
  AND `vefinder_product`.`product_in_stock` = 1 
  AND `vefinder_product_boost`.`target_age_from` >= 20 
  AND `vefinder_product_boost`.`target_age_to` <= 40  
ORDER BY `vefinder_product`.`is_boosted` DESC, 
         `vefinder_product`.`is_sponsered` DESC, 
         `vefinder_product`.`created_date` DESC LIMIT 21
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use third party software like SQLyog.
it is very simple for join query just build query with UI and assign relation to that fields between tables. 
in sqlyog you can get data from multiple tables not only two tables. 
because i am currently using this software for time saving.